# matrix with positive diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I was wondering if a symmetric matrix with positive elements only in the diagonal (negative elsewhere) is any special beside the symmetry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless it happens to be diagonally dominant, I can't think of any other special property, but then again, I am not an expert.

Comment: Some of them have nice properties.  You might want to consider [M-matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That was a nice pointer - thanx!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you